# How to manage text field's in reactive forms for validation in 'angular 2'?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I developed a form using 'reactive forms' in 'angular 2'. Here my form consists of five optional fields and each field can take comma-separated values. Here I am going to control any two fields that are permitted to take comma-separated values, and the remaining fields can take the single value. If user tries to give comma separated values to the more than two fields, should send a popup error message.

I have written 'custom validator' to process comma-separated values, but I'm not clear to have a comma-separated field for only two fields. If you have any idea, please help me.

Here is my Custom validator method.

```
//Custom validator for Unitorder,Orderreference number,Schedule Entry,SAP 
 order number and CPS ID 
  static commaSeparatedFields(min: number, max: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
  var reg=/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/;
    if(c && (c.value !== '')){
      const str=c.value;
      const valArr=str.split(',');
      let OUNArray=[],OCCArray=[];
      for(let val in valArr){
          if ( valArr[val].length<min || valArr[val].length>max || 
    valArr[val].match(reg) ){
            console.log('Invalid');
          return { 
              'commaSeparatedFields' : true
               };
          }else{
            console.log('valid');
          } 
      }
      }
       return null;
     };
    }
```

Comment: thats additional rule. You have to validate agains all fields at once to see if cross-field rule is met.